# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager throws an System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin, mono

I'm having trouble with my code to access a MySQL Database. Everytime I try to open my connection, a `System.TypeInitializationException` is thrown by `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager`. Here is my code:

```
DataTable results = new DataTable("Results");
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=foo;UID=bar;PASSWORD=foobar;"))
{
    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        command.Connection.Open(); //throws System.TypeInitializationException
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        results.Load(reader);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I guess MySQL Driver was corrupt. After an upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 everything worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but when i installed the MySql.Data.dll using Nuget then the problem is solved
Install MySql.Dll file from Nuget,

not from MySQL Website.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string format is wrong. Try this :

```
static string cs = @"server=localhost;user id=bar;password=foobar;database=foo;";
DataTable results = new DataTable("Results");
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(cs))
{
    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        command.Connection.Open(); //throws System.TypeInitializationException
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        results.Load(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your edited connection string, but I still get the same exception.

Comment: Can you try Enabling `"native code debugging" in Project -> Properties -> Debug `? @JanHenry

Comment: I activated it, but I still get the same exception. @ViVi

Comment: Does the machine where the application is running has all the required dlls??

Maybe you are missing some interops in the local directory

Comment: It worked fine yesterday. I've done some changes to other code in the Project, but I did not touch my MySQL code. All DLLs that the application are located at the Debug folder.

Comment: Ensure that all dlls are available and are build as per the current build configuration. ie either x86 or x64.

Comment: I've ensured that. I tried both, x86 and x64. Both dont work.

Comment: There is no possibility of any other issues other than this. 
Connecting to MySQL db just requires the `MySql.Web` & `MySql.Data` dll's and correct credentials. 
If it worked yesterday, then there is no possibility that it shouldn't work today unless there is any change in the dll or connection.
Try creating a test application with mysql.data and mysql.web dll's and try to open a connection.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it raised error only in production. It was due to a wrong assumption in the MySql.Data package. It for some reason seems to demand to be in the same folder as the *orchestrating* dll (it was referencing another dll which was referencing MySql). I resolved my issue by removing [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) and instead installing [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) package as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60786792/7032856).