# The specified invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' wasn't found in the list of registered .NET Data Providers

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core-3.0, .net-standard-2.1

I have a C# Library developed using .Net Standard 2.1 and  this library is called in a test console application built on .Net Core 3.0. But at run time, the GetFactory is throwing an exception.

```
 private DbConnection connection;
 connection = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient").CreateConnection();
```

Exception:

> DbProviderFactories.GetFactory The specified invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' wasn't found in the list of registered .NET Data Providers.

I have installed MySqlConnector 1.2.1. But it didn't help. And also adding the below in app.config file.

```
<system.data>
 <DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The XML you've shown for app.config only works in .NET Framework applications.

For .NET Core 2.1 or later, call [`DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbproviderfactories.registerfactory?view=net-5.0). The exact arguments you pass will depend on the factory you want to register (and the NuGet packages you have installed):

```cs
// MySqlConnector (my personal recommendation for .NET Core)
DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("MySqlConnector", MySqlConnector.MySqlConnectorFactory.Instance);

// MySql.Data (may be needed instead if other code is hard-coded to "MySql.Data.MySqlClient")
DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory.Instance);
```

For more information, see [Using DbProviderFactories](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/dbproviderfactories/).

Comment: Your solution resolved the posted issue. But GetConnectionString(true) method is throwing an exception "The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception." . I know this is a different issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I forgot to remove the above app.config settings and that was causing the ReplicationManager exception. After removing the app.config, its working now!

Comment: @Ullan That error has been reported frequently against MySql.Data (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/65496771/23633, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60786792/23633) which is why I recommended MySqlConnector for .NET Core instead.